# how to connect to remote database in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

[This is view of my phpmyadmin web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8joN.jpg)

I need to connect to my university webserver on PHPmyadmin which is "phpmyadmin.newnumyspace.co.uk"
what changes are required to achieve this. I mean i know localhost would be changed and port and something needs to be put here but help me out as i don't understand the syntax

```
<?php

$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="nbl";

try{
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    

}

catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
{
    
    $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: `phpmyadmin.newnumyspace.co.uk` sounds like the web host, not the mysql host. But if it is, just change the db_host. Unless the port has changed, you don't need to change anything else but the user/pass/database name.

Comment: A lot more information is required. 1. You don't connect to phpmyadmin. You connect to the mysql server. 2. Are you allowed to remotely directly connect to the mysql server or do you need to go through a ssh tunnel? 3. Are you actuly allowed to do what you want to do?

Comment: @JasonK but how would this help to connect to my web host because the webhost isn't even mentioned

Comment: @aynber So i just need to change the localhost to phpmyadmin url and it'll work?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. You need to talk to the host. `PHPMyAdmin` is a web interface for a database, it's not the type of database, and not often used as the host name.

Comment: @aynber im gonna update the question with a web server picture so you can be sure what exactly is it and how it could be achieved

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't mean much. PHPMyAdmin is set to use `localhost`, but you can't use that remotely, since localhost always means the local system. You need to contact your host to find out if and how you can connect to the database remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql DB is local to the web host as they are both run on a linux XAMPP server. Obviously include the correct username and password.

```
function getConnection() {
try {
    /* connects to the SQL DB */
    $connection = new 
    PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=unn_w19038752",
    "unn_w19038752", "Password");
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $connection;
} catch (Exception $e) {
/* displays an error if unable to connect */
throw new Exception("Connection error ". $e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
}
}
```

Then you can just call this function everytime you need to make a connection
($dbConn = getConnection();)

Although for a clearer answer you're better speaking to your KF4009 Module tutor for assistance (That's what you're paying Uni fees for :-) )

Regards, former NU Student :-)

P.S. nbl is a table not a db, and you don't have root access(username), check your email from newnumyspace for your correct server login details.